# How to create multiple sitemap types in Drupal

Tags: drupal-8, sitemap

I want to create multiple sitemap type for node, taxonomy in Drupal 8/9

For example

1 sitemap for "Article" content type
Like: example.com/article-sitemap.xml

1 sitemap for "Basic page" content type
Like: example.com/page-sitemap.xml

1 sitemap for "News" content page
Like: example.com/news-sitemap.xml

And list all this sitemap in sitemap.xml

I tried with different module but didn't get any result I want

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The [Simple XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_sitemap) module can do it out of the box.

After installing,

1. Go to */admin/config/search/simplesitemap* and create your sitemaps. Name them according to your content types/taxonomies and make sure they are of the default hreflang sitemap type.
2. Enable the sitemap index by editing it and changing its status. If it's not been created for you, you can create it manually by creating a sitemap of the index type.
3. Navigate to */admin/config/search/simplesitemap/settings* and set the default sitemap to be the sitemap index. This way the index of your sitemaps will be available under /sitemap.xml.
4. Navigate to */admin/config/search/simplesitemap/entities* and set content/taxonomy types to be included in the specific sitemaps you created.
5. Go back to */admin/config/search/simple_sitemap* and click on 'rebuild queue & generate'.
6. Check the results by visiting */sitemap.xml*.